# How to add data to a spark list control dynamically

Tags: list, dynamic-data

I have a spark list control(id="Cclist") in one of my custom components() and a text input control. When a value is entered into the text input, I want to dynamically add the same into the list control. I tried doing the following :

```
protected function Cc_selectHandler(event:CustomEvent):void
```

{

```
 var cctext:DisplayObject = event.data as DisplayObject
 CcList.enabled = true;
 CcListButton.enabled = true;

 CcList.addChild(cctext);
```

}

But I get an error saying "addChild() is not available in this class. Instead, use addElement() or modify the skin". So I tried using addElement, but apparently that isnt available at all. Any idea what im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<s:List x="732" y="299" width="191" height="108" id="lstQue">
<s:dataProvider>
    <mx:ArrayCollection>

    </mx:ArrayCollection>
</s:dataProvider>
```

Needs a  dataProvider to use the addItem method. A quick and dirty way is just to add a blank dataProvider with a blank ArrayCollection enclosed.

Example of adding to it through a click event.

```
protected function imgAddToList_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
                            this.lstQue.dataProvider.addItem(DataGrid.selectedItem.fldVideoThumb);

        }
```